# OS X Yosemite – full screen with two apps?

Tags: osx-yosemite, fullscreen, osx-spaces

Is it possible to get full screen mode with two apps in OS X Yosemite?

Even with a 3rd party tool perhaps?

The behavior I want is to "lock" two apps (which I use [HyperDock](https://bahoom.com/hyperdock/) to lock to one half of the screen) to a single Desktop/Space, so when I start another app (say, via Spotlight), it doesn't stack on top of the two apps that I have open in this Space.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding it correctly, you want to have two windows share one Desktop/Space fullscreen, and when another app is open, it'll go to another Desktop/Space? If that's the case, then this behavior actually comes default with OS X.

To get this behavior:

1. Drag window 1 to a new space.
2. Drag window 2 to the newly created space, half of the the Desktop/Space should turn gray for window 2 to be placed there.

Now that Desktop/Space has two windows in fullscreen mode, and when you're on that Desktop/Space, any new app opened will go to another Desktop/Space.

Answer (score 0):

Any app set to full screen will automatically go to a new Space of its own, to the right of any existing spaces - see this example with one Safari Window & Mail set as fullscreen, to the right of my 6 existing numbered Spaces…

[image]

You cannot assign any hotkey to go directly to a fullscreen app, only to a numbered Space, but default is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>[Num]</kbd>  &  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>   or  <kbd>→</kbd>  to go to last/next, so to get there quickly I use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>6</kbd>  /  <kbd>→</kbd> 
You can set those up in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control.

Other than in fullscreen, you can set any app to a specific Space by launching it in that Space or dragging it there by the header bar + key combo, then right click in the Dock & Options > Assign to… This Desktop.

[image]

Any app which doesn't have an assigned Space will always open in the current one, unless the current Space is an auto-generated fullscreen Space.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/) to bind custom commands to open apps.

For example, I have this combinations among others:

- <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>: Open/View Chrome
- <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>: Open/View Atom
- <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>: Open/View Terminal
- <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>: Open/View Spotify

That way I don't have to worry what app was last used and just insert the shortcut to open the app that I want.